# Errors setting up hadoop 3.2.0 Pseudo-Distribution Operation

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

As a newbie in hadoop, I  successfully installed hadoop 3.2.0 on my ubuntu following its documentation from the link

> https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

. However, I am having issues carrying out some execution process leading to the examples in the Psuedo-Distributed Operations section.

[image]
when I run this code`$ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir input` i seem to get the following error

```
mkdir: `hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop3': No such file or directory
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here. kindly assist. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first create your user directory

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hadoop3
```

If you do not prefix a filepath (starting at the root of HDFS), it assumes your user directory, by default